# Theming Telegram Panel Icon (ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: 15.10, indicator, panel, telegram

I'm adapting an icon theme (FlatWoken) to fit my desktop.
I seem to have a problem with Telegram icon. I can set a dash icon but no luck with the top panel indicator, as you can see in the picture below.

[image: Detail of Dash and top panel]

I have created a telegramdesktop.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Telegram Desktop
Comment=Official desktop version of Telegram messaging app
Exec=/home/<myuser>/.local/share/applications/Telegram/Telegram -- %u
Icon=telegramdesktop
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Telegram
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
MimeType=application/x-xdg-protocol-tg;x-scheme-handler/tg;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

and placed my custom icons in

```
<iconthemefolder>/scalable/telegrandesktop.svg
<iconthemefolder>/22x22/telegrandesktop.svg
```

The scalable icon seems to work,the 22x22 not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The icon used for the systemtray is stored under ~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/tdata/ticons/*!

I produced icons fitting for the breeze theme:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gzfpu7zgwk2n1l/telegram.zip?dl=0
You can do this yourself, just use the script included in the .zip file :)

If you want telegram to autostart with a nice logo you have to delay it.
(sleep 2 was sufficient for me)

Some recommodations for telegram, icluding the ones above:

1. Download every file from: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ed8aq9x756qq08o/AACw89mbvl4oHjd6zeuq1xVUa?dl=0 to your home folder
2. execute "sudo su"
3. execute "./telegram.sh /home/manu" <- to REPLACE
4. Settings -> Startup and Shutdown (under Workspace) -> Desktop Session ->
   on Login -> Applications to be excluded from sessions: program.telegram

Comment: Very interesting. I have to try that and check why my /tdata/ticons is under ~/.TelegramDesktop
Thank you